# How to fill in gaps in a chart with datasets from different time stamps

Tags: anychart

How to fill in gaps in a chart with datasets from different time stamps?
Follow the link script and screen diagram.
https://mega.nz/folder/XoBlQYTJ#vZ7-UeDOojIg8HXGBenkBA

Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid missings you can enable connectMissingPoints() settings for every series. For details, check [the modified sample](https://playground.anychart.com/yDMd5pak).

You can learn more about this setting in [the API reference](https://api.anychart.com/?entry=connectMissingPoints).